# How to divide the padding equally among item in a ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I have an HStack and a ForEach inside it, I'm showing 5 child views, but my problem is that the padding differs, and also, when for example I change the text to a longer text for example, (33% to 100%) the height changes too. I want them to be divided equally among the screen.

Parent Code:

```swift
// Last 5 Days Horizontal List
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(last5Days) { day in
        Button {
            print("last 5 days clicked \(day.date)")
        } label: {
            CalendarItemMainPageView(passedDay: day)
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}.padding(.horizontal)
```

Child View Code

```swift
VStack {
    let dayAbbreviation = svm.getDayAbbreviation(from: passedDay.date)
    let isToday = svm.checkIsToday(for: passedDay.date)
    Text(dayAbbreviation)
        .foregroundStyle(isToday ? .fDarkBlue : .fDarkBlue)
        .font(.headline)
        .padding(.top, 5)
        .lineLimit(1)
    
    let dayInt = svm.getDayInt(from: passedDay.date)
    Text(String(dayInt))
        .foregroundStyle(isToday ? .fDarkBlue : .fDarkBlue)
        .font(.system(size: 20))
        .bold()
        .lineLimit(1)
    
    let percentageCompleted = vm.getPercentageCompleted(percent: passedDay.percentageCompleted)
    Text(String(Int(percentageCompleted * 100)) + "%")
        .font(.caption)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .foregroundStyle(isToday ? .fDarkBlue : .fDarkBlue)
        .padding(.bottom, 2)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
    
}
.minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
.background {
    let isToday = svm.checkIsToday(for: passedDay.date)

    Rectangle()
        .fill(isToday ? .fYellow : .fYellow)
        .cornerRadius(8.0)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
}
.padding(5)
.background {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color(backgroundColor.rawValue))
        .cornerRadius(3.0)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
}
.onAppear {
    let isToday = svm.checkIsToday(for: passedDay.date)
    let percentageCompleted = vm.getPercentageCompleted(percent: passedDay.percentageCompleted)

    if !isToday {
        if percentageCompleted * 100 < 50.0 {
            backgroundColor = .pink
        }
    } else {
        backgroundColor = .pink
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use a button. I would use. A view with an `onTapped`

Comment: `Button` is better because you get highlighting on press for free. Using `Button` here isn't causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting `frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` on the `CalendarItemMainPageView` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` modifier is not a good choice in this case. Better solution will be to make the content of `CalendarItemMainPageView` scalable by applying `frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` on any of the containing texts.

So the final code will be...

Parent Code:

```
HStack(spacing: 0) { // <-- Change the spacing here
    ForEach(last5Days) { day in
        Button {
            print("last 5 days clicked \(day.date)")
        } label: {
            CalendarItemMainPageView(passedDay: day)  // <-- Removed padding, now you can configure the distance by changing the spacing in the HStack
        }
    }
}.padding(.horizontal)
```

Child View Code:

```
VStack {
    let dayAbbreviation = svm.getDayAbbreviation(from: passedDay.date)
    let isToday = svm.checkIsToday(for: passedDay.date)
    Text(dayAbbreviation)
        .foregroundStyle(isToday ? .fDarkBlue : .fDarkBlue)
        .font(.headline)
        .padding(.top, 5)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // <-- Added this
    
    let dayInt = svm.getDayInt(from: passedDay.date)
    Text(String(dayInt))
        .foregroundStyle(isToday ? .fDarkBlue : .fDarkBlue)
        .font(.system(size: 20))
        .bold()
        .lineLimit(1)
    
    let percentageCompleted = vm.getPercentageCompleted(percent: passedDay.percentageCompleted)
    Text(String(Int(percentageCompleted * 100)) + "%")
        .font(.caption)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .foregroundStyle(isToday ? .fDarkBlue : .fDarkBlue)
        .padding(.bottom, 2)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
}
.minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
.background {
    let isToday = svm.checkIsToday(for: passedDay.date)

    Rectangle()
        .fill(isToday ? .fYellow : .fYellow)
        .cornerRadius(8.0)  // // <-- Removed aspect ratio
}
.padding(5)
.background {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color(backgroundColor.rawValue))
        .cornerRadius(3.0)  // <-- Removed aspect ratio
}
.onAppear {
    let isToday = svm.checkIsToday(for: passedDay.date)
    let percentageCompleted = vm.getPercentageCompleted(percent: passedDay.percentageCompleted)

    if !isToday {
        if percentageCompleted * 100 < 50.0 {
            backgroundColor = .pink
        }
    } else {
        backgroundColor = .pink
    }
}
```